# Azure B2C Add custom signin policy

Tags: azure-active-directory, azure-ad-b2c

I am trying to add simple SignIn custom policy using userName and password.
If i use  `<Item Key="ContentDefinitionReferenceId">api.localaccountsignin</Item>`
it will show SignUp button as well which i dont want(i need just signIn policy),
I also tried to use `<Item Key="ContentDefinitionReferenceId">api.selfasserted</Item>` but ended up as shown below 
[image]

Below is my technical profile

```
 <TechnicalProfile Id="SelfAsserted-LocalAccountSignin-Email">
      <DisplayName>Local Account Signin</DisplayName>
      <Protocol Name="Proprietary" Handler="Web.TPEngine.Providers.SelfAssertedAttributeProvider, Web.TPEngine, Version=1.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=null" />
      <Metadata>
        <Item Key="setting.operatingMode">Username</Item>
        <Item Key="ContentDefinitionReferenceId">api.selfasserted</Item>
      </Metadata>
      <IncludeInSso>false</IncludeInSso>
      <InputClaims>
        <InputClaim ClaimTypeReferenceId="signInName" />
      </InputClaims>
      <OutputClaims>
        <OutputClaim ClaimTypeReferenceId="signInName" Required="true" />
        <OutputClaim ClaimTypeReferenceId="password" Required="true" />
        <OutputClaim ClaimTypeReferenceId="objectId" />
      </OutputClaims>
      <ValidationTechnicalProfiles>
        <ValidationTechnicalProfile ReferenceId="login-NonInteractive" />
      </ValidationTechnicalProfiles>
      <UseTechnicalProfileForSessionManagement ReferenceId="SM-AAD" />
    </TechnicalProfile>
```

Below is my User journey

```
 <UserJourney Id="SignIn">
 <OrchestrationSteps>
  <OrchestrationStep Order="1" Type="ClaimsExchange">
      <ClaimsExchanges>
        <ClaimsExchange Id="LocalAccountSigninEmailExchange1" TechnicalProfileReferenceId="SelfAsserted-LocalAccountSignin-Email" />
      </ClaimsExchanges>
  </OrchestrationStep>
  <OrchestrationStep Order="2" Type="ClaimsExchange">
      <ClaimsExchanges>
        <ClaimsExchange Id="AADUserReadWithObjectId" TechnicalProfileReferenceId="AAD-UserReadUsingObjectId" />
      </ClaimsExchanges>
  </OrchestrationStep>
    <OrchestrationStep Order="3" Type="SendClaims" CpimIssuerTechnicalProfileReferenceId="JwtIssuer" />
  </OrchestrationSteps>
  <ClientDefinition ReferenceId="DefaultWeb" />
 </UserJourney>
```

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If you do not want the SignUp button add the following Metadata item;

`<Item Key="setting.showSignupLink">False</Item>`

Comment: Awesome thanks.It was hard for me to find the documentation for all Azure AD b2c custom policies.Do you know links to the right documentaion?

Comment: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-gb/azure/active-directory-b2c/active-directory-b2c-overview-custom

Comment: Here is a link to the actual list of accepted metadata https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/active-directory-b2c/self-asserted-technical-profile#metadata